# How to reduce selecting field for database performance when calling instance dot field in django orm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

When need to check a field value of an instance when use dot(.) for accessing the field as follows.

```
class store(models.Model):
  ........
  is_open = models.BooleanField(defrault=False)
  ........

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  ........
  store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
  ........
```

I need to check the value of `is_open` in some API I do as follows,

```
request.user.store.is_open
```

In this case, django performs a select query with all fields but I only need the `is_open` field.

How can I only select only a single field (`is_open` in this case) instead of selecting all fields?

Comment: `values` or  `values_list` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: @hansTheFranz Thanks, But user is a single instance here, How can I use `values` or `values_list` over here?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the performance gain is minimal but try this:

```
is_open = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).values('store__is_open').first()['store__is_open']
```